# Rails Multi tenancy using Apartment gem on Amazon AWS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, apartment-gem

I have previously used apartment on Heroku, but now for a client, I am evaluating if it can be used on AWS. Is there a tutorial that shows how to use the apartment gem on Amazon AWS?

After reading https://aws.amazon.com/running_databases/ , I am not sure how to setup my database.
Should I install postgres on my instance or should I use RDS? Does the RDS allow creating multiple schemas if I use Postgres.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apartment isn't tied to any hosting provider. It just uses Postgres (by default) for its db. Heroku vs AWS/RDS won't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can use RDS. Best to just try it out-- setup a new RDS instance with the aws console then plug the connection string into your rails database.yml config and then run your migrations (`rake db:migrate`) or load your schema (`rake db:schema:load`).